# How do I open a document (eg. .txt) in another app from a Python Script mac

Tags: python

How and is it possible to open a document in a GUI text editor such as Word from a python script on a Mac? For example, do something like this:

Open x.txt in Word.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is how you can do it on Mac OS:

If you want to open a file with a specific application on Mac OS, you do:

```
$ open -a appName fileName
```

So, for example you want to open `hello.docx` with `Pages` app, you do:

```
$ open -a pages path/hello.docx
```

Similarly to open a file with Word:

```
$ open -a "Microsoft Word.app" path/hello.docx
```

### How you do it from Python (still only Mac OS):

Now, we need to be able to call shell commands from Python. There are several ways of doing it. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) for a variety of ways.

One simple way of doing it would be:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('open -a "Microsoft Word.app" path/hello.docx')
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!